# How to make animation runned and then stopped in CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I try make button to change color using hover and animation. But, when animation loops, color of button comes back to basic version. How can I fix it? Is there any css property to do it? Or bundle of rules? Or maybe I have to go to JS and write some code?

```css
#launch-button {
    width: 440px;
    height: 100px;
    margin-top: 75%;
    margin-left: 15%;
    border-radius: 45px;
    border-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

#launch-button:hover {
    animation-name: change-background;
    animation-duration: 0.75s;
    animation-delay: 0s;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in;
}

@keyframes change-background {
    to {background-color: rgba(26, 198, 250, 0.5);}
}
```

Comment: try adding `animation-fill-mode: forwards;` in your hover state, read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-fill-mode)

Comment: you've set your animation to run once with `animation-iteration-count: 1;`, so after the animation is done, it will return to its original state. therefore it's not actually "looping", you're just running the animation over and over again while hovering your mouse over the button.

what is it you want exactly? do you want the buttons color to be the one from the animation after the animation has run? or do you want the animation to include more colors?

Answer (score 0):

```css
#launch-button {
    width: 440px;
    height: 100px;
    margin-top: 75%;
    margin-left: 15%;
    border-radius: 45px;
    border-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

#launch-button:hover {
    animation: forwards;
    animation-name: change-background;
    animation-duration: 0.75s;
    animation-delay: 0s;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in;
}

@keyframes change-background {
    to {background-color: rgba(26, 198, 250, 0.5);}
}
```

```html
<button type="button" id="launch-button">Hello, world!</button>
```

All that was needed here is `animation: forwards;`. It keeps the button as the last state of the animation without resetting it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe ?? I'm not sure if I understand you right but, If you mean set a time out so your animation will last in particular secs, you can attain it this way. Let me know.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){ 
 $('#launch-button').hover(function(){
   $("#launch-button").css("background-color", "rgba(26, 198, 250, 0.5)");
    setTimeout(function() {
    $("#launch-button").css("background-color", "rgb(255, 255, 255)");   
  }, 5000);
  });  
});
```

```css
#launch-button {
    width: 440px;
    height: 100px;
    margin-top: 0%;
    margin-left: 15%;
    border-radius: 45px;
    border-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="launch-button">
</button>
```